# XSLT - Search for last element in a group

Tags: xml, xslt

I am iterating over a group of elements and while I am iterating I need to access information from the last node set.

For example, I have a test that goes back out to the level1 elements, while I am getting the values for the current node set, to check and see if there are multiple elements that contain the same group number, and then if so would need to access information from the last node set that contains the group with number 3.

```
<root>
    <level1>
        <group>1</group>
        <name>test1</name>
        <email>test@email.com</email>
    </level1>
    <level1>
        <group>3</group>
        <name>test2</name>
        <email>test2@email.com</email>
    </level1>
    <level1>
        <group>3</group>
        <name>test3</name>
        <email>test3@email.com</email>
        <manager>manager@email.com</email>
    </level1>
</root>
```

I have tried the following to get back out to the root level to check to see if the group exists and to get the last node set that contains the specific group.

```
../../level1/group = ./group

./group = ../../level1/group

./group = ../../level1/group[1][last()]
```

Comment: It's not clear where are you when you iterate, what exactly do you need to know and - most importantly - why. Once you clarify that, I suspect the answer will be quite different from what you expect. Most likely it will turn out that this is a question about grouping. -- Also please state if you are using XSLT 1.0 or 2.0.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to locate the last  tag for group 3, you can do the following:

```
root/level1[group = 3][position() = last()]
```

Comment: `root/level1[group = 3 and position() = last()]` does **NOT** select "*the last tag for group 3*". It selects the last of **ALL** `level1` elements, **IF** its group number is 3. Otherwise it selects nothing.

Comment: I suspect OP wants to know if the current `level1` element is the last of its group; so hard-coding the group number is not the way to go.